# Celery on Heroku doesn't shutdown properly when I automatically deploy from github

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

The problem I am having is surrounding the restarting process of Celery during an app version release in Heroku. Every time I push code to my production GitHub it does this:

```
2020-07-29T15:09:13.725295+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
2020-07-29T15:09:13.725295+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-07-29T15:09:13.725295+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 22
2020-07-29T15:09:13.725296+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from . import async, base
2020-07-29T15:09:13.725296+00:00 app[worker.1]:                   ^
2020-07-29T15:09:13.725296+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2020-07-29T15:09:14.451767+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-29T15:09:14.516084+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Then I have to manually push code again and the celery works just fine. This happens every single time. Is there a way to prevent the celery app from trying to start up before the other app is done shutting down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error [comes from a problem with `celery<=4.2` and `python>=3.7`](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4849). `async` became a keyword in python 3.7.

I'm not sure why this error is transient for you, but the solution is either [to specify a 3.6 python version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) or to upgrade to `celery>=4.3`.

To answer the question about dyno startup:
What Heroku does sounds like [`preboot`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot) is active for your app. Its a technique that actually reduces your downtime when deploying new code, at the cost of old and new code running side by side. You can deactivate it as stated in the article.